# How to capture shell script output

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

I have an unix shell script. I have put `-x` in shell to see all the execution step. Now I want to capture these in one log file on a daily basis.
Psb script.

```
#!/bin/ksh -x   
Logfile= path.log.date    
Print " copying file" | tee $logifle     
Scp  -i key source destination | tee -a $logfile.    
Exit 0;
```

Comment: `Logfile= path.log.date` is a bug. You cannot have spaces in an assignment in shell. It should be `Logfile=path.log.date`. This isn't your actual script is it? (You have some case sensitivity issues too)

Comment: Ok thanks rest all look goods?

Answer (score 1):

First line of the shell script  is known as **shebang** , which indicates what interpreter has to be execute the below script.

Similarly first line is commented which denotes coming lines not related to that interpreted session.

To capture the output, run the script redirect your output while running the script.

```
ksh -x scriptname >> output_file
```

Note:it will output what your script's doing line by line

Comment: #!bin/ksh -x >> $ Logfile

Logfile= path.log.date

Print " copying file" | tee -a $logifle

Scp -i key source destination | tee -a $logfile.

Exit 0;

Is the above is right? Or do I need to remove tee command

Answer (score 0):

There are two cases, using `ksh` as your shell, then you need to do IO redirection accordingly, and using some other shell and executing a `.ksh` script, then IO redirection could be done based on that shell. Following method should work for most of the shells.

```
$ cat somescript.ksh
#!/bin/ksh -x

printf "Copy file \n";
printf "Do something else \n";
```

Run it:

```
$ ./somescript.ksh 1>some.log 2>&1
```

`some.log` will contain,

```
+ printf 'Copy file \n'
Copy file 
+ printf 'Do something else \n'
Do something else
```

In your case, *no need* to specify `logfile` and/or `tee`. Script would look something like this,

```
#!/bin/ksh -x      
printf "copying file\n"    
scp -i key user@server /path/to/file   
exit 0
```

Run it:

```
$ ./myscript 1>/path/to/logfile 2>&1
```

`2>&1` captures both `stderr` and `stdout` into `stdout` and `1>logfile` prints it out into `logfile`.

Comment: Thank you..Actually I want to creat a shell script and us line. ed .sh in control-m command How can I add  1&gt;some.log  2&amp;&gt;1 after.sh in controlm command line.Pls help.thanks

Comment: Thank you. How can I use this stderr and stout in control-m command line. Because I want to use in control-m job

Comment: I don't know anything about `control-m-job`. You can ask that as a separate question. The command line in itself should be standalone, if you are using `ksh` or any shell. and see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to explicitly redirecting the output (including stderr `2>` because `set -x` sends output to stderr).

This keeps the shebang short and you don't have to cram the redirecton and filename-building into it.

```
#!/bin/ksh
logfile=path.log.date
exec >> $logfile 2>&1  # redirecting all output to logfile (appending)
set -x               # switch on debugging
# now start working
echo "print something"
```